# Is there any module to parse CAN database (.dbc) files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, can-bus, j1939

```
import cantoools
can_db = cantools.database.load_file(path)
```

above snippet shows error

> "signal_xx" over lapping in message "node_xx"

please suggest other ways to parse this info.

path ---> CAN BASE J1939

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the [cantools](https://github.com/cantools/cantools) project, but the message seems pretty explicit to me.

> :signal_xx" over lapping in message "node_xx"

It means that in the DBC, there is a frame named `node_xx` with at least 2 signals which are overlapping. This means that there are one or several bits which are used by more than one signal.

The DBC file seems malformed!

You could download the de-facto standard [candb++](https://www.vector.com/int/en/download/?tx_vecdownload_downloaddetail%5Bdownload%5D=65339&cHash=fa35ecb974afc69ad5ebd3a5661d3f92) from VECTOR, while *not* being a free software, it can be downloaded for free. That software should be able to report some warnings or errors if there are signals overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing it correctly but there's an issue with the DBC file itself. You can use CANdb++ like Robert suggested (it installs automatically alongside any Vector software install like CANalyzer) or just open the DBC file in a text editor. You're looking for a message where signals overlap. Each signal has a start bit and number of bits defined so somewhere there's a conflict.